# Solution for Data issue

Tags: sql

I have an table as below.

```
AppKey                            Customer

1009                                    Stell

1009                                     -
```

Following is the script.

```
Select AppKey , Customer
FROM table
```

I want to exclude records that has null on Customer which I can easily achieve it by using where customer is notnull;

But I might have an record like below which I want to include even though the customer field is Null. How can I achieve this on the script?

```
AppKey                            Customer

1000                                      -
```

Thanks very much!!

Comment: Why doesn't `WHERE customer IS NOT NULL` work? `-` is not NULL

Comment: Tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Comment: To clarify, if multiple app keys exists, you want the not NULL one.   However, if a single app key exist, and the customer field is null, you want that record as well?  Also, if there are 3 1009's (in your example), 2 of which have valyues, which do you want?

Comment: Your question is unclear; what is the difference between the rows you want to exclude and the rows you don't? Does "-" represent NULL in both cases?

Comment: What is special about Appkey 1000, other than its own value?

Comment: If there are 3 1009's then any No NULL one is enough, most likely there will be 2 1009's. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some aggregation.

```
SELECT AppKey, Max(Customer) FROM table GROUP BY Appkey;
```

Note this will turn funky if you have more than one non-null `Customer` record for a distinct `Appkey`.